# Sorted Linked List gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am creating a Sorted Linked List where integers are stored in ascending order. I am having a trouble with add() method. It works when I add first node but when I try to add another one it gives me `NullPointerException`

Here is my code for Node class:

```
public class Node {
  int value;
  Node next;

  public Node() {
  }

  public Node(int c) {
    this.value = c;
  }

  public boolean hasNext() {
    if (next == null) {
       return false;
    } else {
       return true;
  }


}
```

And this is part of my SortedList class:

```
  public class SortedList {

    Node head;
    public int listCount;


    public SortedList() {
      listCount = 0;
      this.head=null;
    }

    public void add(int num) {
      Node newNode = new Node(num);
      Node temp = head;

      if (head == null) {
        head = newNode;
        listCount++;
        System.out.println("Node with data "+num+" was added.");
       } else {
        while (temp.value <= num) {    //the compiler shows NullPointerException here in this line 
            temp = temp.next;
        }
          if (temp.next==null) {
            temp.next=newNode;
            listCount++;
            System.out.println("Node with data "+num+" was added.");
        } else {
            newNode.next=temp.next.next;
            temp.next=newNode;
            listCount++;
            System.out.println("Node with data "+num+" was added.");
        }


    }

}
```

It says that the java.lang.NullPointerException is at  "while (temp.value <= num)" line

Comment: So think about what should happen if the number you're adding is bigger than every number that's already in the list.  It looks to me like that loop will keep going until `temp` becomes null, and that can't possibly be what you want, right?

Answer (score 0):

Consider these lines of your program:

```
while (temp.value <= num) { 
    temp = temp.next;
}
```

Each time through the loop, `temp` is accessed in order to retrieve its `value`, and if that value is less than or equal to `num`, you move on to the `next` node.

However, there's nothing in this code that handles what happens when you hit the "end" of your sorted list (and therefore `temp.next` is `null`). When that happens, `null` is assigned to `temp`, and then the loop condition is checked again and `temp.value` throws a NullPointerException.

Exactly how you solve this is somewhat a matter of preference. Probably you want to stop when `temp` holds the tail of the list. So perhaps you could change the loop condition to

```
while (temp.value <= num && temp.next != null)
```

Comment: so I did change my while loop but now I am facing another problem. When I add nodes to my linked list it only saves first two nodes and the last one. All the other entrees are not in the linked list.

Comment: @Marina you should open a new question about that